Problem in solving an integral equation.
The Question
Given the following integral equation:
$$\exp(2x) = \int_0^x f(x-t)\cos t \, \mathrm{d}t,$$
find $f(x)$.
My Solution
Let $u = x - t$ in the integral, then I get
$$\exp(2x) = \int_0^x f(u)\cos (x-u) \, \mathrm{d}u. \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
Differentiate both sides twice:
$$4\exp(2x) = f'(x) - \int_0^x f(u)\cos (x-u) \, \mathrm{d}u. \tag{2}$$
Substitute the integral on RHS with $\eqref{eq1}$, I get
$$4\exp(2x) = f'(x) - \exp(x).$$
Therefore $f(x) = \frac{5}{2}\exp(2x) + C$.
The Problem
I put the result back to the original integral, and get
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^x f(x-t)\cos t \, \mathrm{d}t &= \int_0^x \frac{5}{2}\exp(2(x-t))\cos t \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \exp(2x) - \cos x + \frac{\sin x}{2}.
\end{aligned}$$
It doesn't match the original equation.
So what is going wrong in my solution, and how can I solve that equation correctly?

$$\left( \int_0^x f(u)\cos (x-u) , \mathrm{d}u\right)'=f(x)-\int_0^x f(u)\sin(x-u) , \mathrm{d}u.$$

@Riemann That's true, but I differentiate both sides for twice.

I see now, twice.

Youe equation$$\exp(2x) = \int_0^x f(x-t)\cos t , \mathrm{d}t,$$ when $x=0$ ,we have $1=0$???

Assuming $x \ge 0$ we can apply the Laplace transform so
$$
\mathscr{L}(e^{2x})=\mathscr{L}(f(x)\circledast \cos x)
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{s-2}=\hat f(s)\frac{s}{s^2+1}
$$
and then
$$
\hat f(s) = \frac{s^2+1}{s(s-2)}
$$
so the inverse is
$$
f(x) = \frac{5 e^{2 x}}{2} -\frac{1}{2} + \delta (x)
$$
Here $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.

[+1] But it should be said that the star operator is convolution, because it isn't evident for a newcomer in the domain to recognize it.

I think your equation should be
$$\exp(2x)-1= \int_0^x f(x-t)\cos t \, \mathrm{d}t,\tag{*}$$
(otherwise $1=0$ when we take $x=0$).
Let $u = x - t$ in the integral, then I get
$$\exp(2x)-1 = \int_0^x f(u)\cos (x-u) \, \mathrm{d}u. \tag{1}$$
Differentiate both sides twice:
$$4\exp(2x) = f'(x) - \int_0^x f(u)\cos (x-u) \, \mathrm{d}u. \tag{2}$$
Subsititute the integral on RHS with $(1)$, I get
$$4\exp(2x) = f'(x) - \exp(2x)+1.$$
Therefore $f(x) = \frac{5}{2}\exp(2x)-x + C$.
If you put the result back to the original integral, and get
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^x f(x-t)\cos t \, \mathrm{d}t &= \int_0^x \left(\frac{5}{2}\exp(2(x-t)-x+C\right)-\cos t \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&=\frac{\left(2C + 1\right) \sin\left(x\right)}{2} + \mathrm{e}^{2x} - 1.
\end{aligned}$$
Choose $C=\frac{-1}2$, that will be
$$\exp(2x)-1= \int_0^x f(x-t)\cos t \, \mathrm{d}t.$$
So
$$f(x)=\frac{5}{2}\exp(2x)-x -\frac{1}2.$$

I've noticed the $1=0$ problem, too. My friend shared this question with me, saying it's from master's entrance exam of a college. Maybe it should be like you said.

@Windy_D If in the scope of classic calculus,  the function $f$ should be continuous. And  it doesn't appear $0=1$ and Dirac $\delta$ function. So in this sense, I treat it as a problem in the calculus (or mathemtical analysis 数学分析).
